# How to automatically update migration file based on updated model in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Can we update our migration file based on model where we have updated? I know we have command php artisan make:model modelname --m to create model and migration in same time. But when i updated the model, the migration still same (cannot updated automatically)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is currently no command for achieving this.

However, it is not recommended to update your migrations at all. You should change your database layout with a new migration instead of an updated old, so your database can keep track of changes.

Comment: So we must define manually twice for each table (model and migration) ?

Comment: Yes, for the moment there is not other solution (that I know of).

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.

Answer (score 1):

You should not be changing existing migrations! What if there's another developer working on the project and you changed the migration, merged it to the main branch and then he's left wondering why won't his database run?

Always create new migrations instead of modifying previous ones. Otherwise you will break other people's installations.